# Difference between Python and Postgres locale currency formats

Tags: python, postgresql, locale, currency

Python 2.6:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'fr_CA.UTF-8')
locale.currency(1.234) # '1,23 $'
```

Postgres 9.1:

```
set lc_monetary = 'fr_CA.UTF-8';
select 1.234::money; -- '$1,23'
```

I think the Python version is the right one (not 100% sure though), but how can they possibly be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Lane reported on the PG-general mailing list, this issue is fixed in 9.2:

```
Support more locale-specific formatting options for the money
data type (Tom Lane)

Specifically, honor all the POSIX options for ordering of the
value, sign, and currency symbol in monetary output. Also, make
sure that the thousands separator is only inserted to the left
of the decimal point, as required by POSIX.
```

I tried it with 9.2.4 on OSX, and indeed it works.

Answer (score 1):

Canada has two currency formats (and they may well be unique in that respect). There is English-Canadian (en_CA) and French-Canadian (fr_CA).

With my limited understanding, Python's format appears correct for French-Canadian, whereas PostgreSQL seems to be using English-Canadian.

It's entirely possible that the currency support in PostgreSQL only allows one format per country. It's not had a lot of care and attention over the years, most people using numeric for their financial calculations and then letting the client code handle formatting.

If it's important to you, might be worth posting a bug report (or even a patch).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I was using `numeric` as well until this morning, when I had the sudden intuition that it might be better to handle money formatting and rounding at the DB level (rather than the application level), but then I ran into this issue. So I guess that a followup question would be: is it really be a better idea (i.e. presuming that the issue can be fixed)?

Comment: Well, numeric gives you control over maximum value and maximum precision on a per-column (or calculation) basis. The money type is basically a big integer with a decimal point faked through the lc_monetary configuration setting. If I was already using numeric, I'm not sure I'd switch.